# How to check redundancy in for loop

Tags: javascript

I am pulling some information from an API and one of my fields may or may not have duplicate content. How do I identify the redundancy and not print it on the screen if it's a duplicate?

Here's my loop, and "Description" is the field that sometimes has the same content as its previous sibling:

```
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    htmlString += '<li><h3 class="session-item">' + data[i].Title + '</h3>';
    htmlString += '<p class="session-description">' + data[i].Description + '</p></li>';
}
```

Is this something I should check/compare with the previous sibling or is there a better way?

I tried a simple comparison but this didn't work:

```
var tempDesc = document.getElementsByClassName('session-description');
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    htmlString += '<li><h3 class="session-item">' + data[i].Title + '</h3>';
    if(tempDesc === data[i].Description) {
        htmlString += '</li>';
    } esle {
        htmlString += '<p class="session-description">' + data[i].Description + '</p></li>';
    }
}
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns elements in an array. You are comparing `tempDesc` to `Description` which is a string I assume, it is never going be equal. tempDesc is an array

Comment: Are you sure it isn't `Title` that's redundant? I don't think it would make sense the other way around.

Comment: Are you confident that duplicates will be sequential and not separated by one or more indices?  How big is the dataset/ how important is efficiency?  For example, doing it in a single loop will be more efficient but perhaps less readable; if your data is small enough, you can first loop it to eliminate duplicates and _then_ loop it again to write it to the page.  Also, I would avoid doing comparisons in/against the DOM when you could just do it in JS directly.

Comment: @catgirlkelly, yes pretty sure :) but it will be the same concept so it doesn't matter which field is redundant

Comment: @AlexanderNied that does make sense. It's not a huge dataset, about maybe 170 objects in this API call. Do you have an example code to loop/eliminate duplicates? I still need the Title of the items with duplicate Description, so definitely don't want to remove the whole item.

Comment: @Inder, you're right. Looking into that now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the index so a simple solution is to get the last index with `i - 1`:

```js
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    htmlString += '<li><h3 class="session-item">' + data[i].Title + '</h3>';
    

    if (data[i].Description !== data[i - 1].Description) {
        htmlString += '<p class="session-description">' + data[i].Description + '</p></li>';
    } else {
        htmlString += '</li>';
    }
}
```

But you want to check if it `data[i - 1]` exists first:

```
if (data[i].Description !== (data[i - 1] && data[i - 1].Description)) {
```

If you want a shorter answer then you could use the more advanced optional chaining:

```
if (data[i].Description !== data[i - 1]?.Description) {
```

Comment: My hero! That did it and it makes a lot of sense :) thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
const isEqual = (...objects) => objects.every(obj => JSON.stringify(obj) === JSON.stringify(objects[0]));
data.reduce((x,y) => (x.filter(x => isEqual(x, y)).length > 0) ? x : x.concat([y]), []);
```

then, use `data` with every way you want, all elements are unique :)

Answer (score 0):

Presuming your dataset looks something like this:

```
const apiResponse = [
  { Title: 'Sanity and Tallulah', Description: 'Description 1' },
  { Title: 'Zita the Space Girl', Description: 'Description 2' },
  { Title: 'Lumberjanes', Description: 'Description 1' },
];
```

...and I am understanding your goal correctly that you want to suppress duplicate descriptions but keep the titles, I would suggest one approach is to use a `Set` as you are looping to add to the DOM, and check to see if the description is already present in the `Set` before writing it.  Something like:

```js
const apiResponse = [
  { Title: 'Sanity and Tallulah', Description: 'Description 1' },
  { Title: 'Zita the Space Girl', Description: 'Description 2' },
  { Title: 'Lumberjanes', Description: 'Description 1' },
];

const descriptions = new Set();

for (let item of apiResponse) {
    document.body.append(item.Title)
    document.body.append(document.createElement('br'))
    if (!descriptions.has(item.Description)) {
      descriptions.add(item.Description);
      document.body.append(item.Description)
      document.body.append(document.createElement('br'))
      document.body.append(document.createElement('br'))
    }
}
```

This approach would allow a single loop and avoid having to do comparisons in/against the DOM as a source of truth.

Another option (explored in other answers already) is to first loop the responses and eliminate duplicate values and *then* loop to push to the DOM.

Comment: Thank you Alexander, this works too, I see what you did with Set(), really appreciate the effort but the previous answer requires less tweaking in my existing code.